# How to perform analysis of jstack output using IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, jstack

Is there a way to parse and analyze jstack output in IntelliJ. It can be done in Eclipse but I'm not able to figure out how in IntelliJ 13. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyze | Analyze Stacktrace...